# Where is data cached when using a Cloud TPU?

Tags: google-cloud-tpu

I have a question regarding using using TPU. When I use .cache() with dataset, where is the data cached? Is it cached in RAM of the VM instance rented (e.g. n1-standard-2) or in the memory of TPU. In other words, if I have a ~30G dataset, do I need to rent a VM instance with RAM > 30G to effectively cache the data, or the data is cached in TPU memory, and I don’t need to worry about VM instance size.

The same question goes to where is data augmentation conducted, in the CPU of VM instance or CPU in TPU?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.cache()` it will try to cache the dataset on the TPU VM, not on the GCE VM (eg. n1-standard-2), which should be able to fit fine in this case since TPU VM has way more RAM available than that. However, in general you do not want to call that when running on TPUs as we use GCSFileSystem which does the caching in the background of TFRecord shards: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/gcs_file_system.cc